# how to copy android home shortcuts from one device to another?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, home-screen, samsung-galaxy-tab, home-screen-shortcuts

I have 2 Android (2.2) Galaxy Tab mini tablets with android 2.2 I am setting them up for show presentations.

I put on both of them a directory filled with content. The directory is identical in both devices.

On one I set up many home screen shortcuts to the files in that directory.

How do i COPY all the short cuts from one device to the other ? Where are these shortcuts physically located ? in some kind of home application settings file ? where is it on the file system ?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use a backup program like Titanium Backup to perform a full backup of apps and data and then transfer that backup file to the second device. After this, restoring said backup on the second device *should* transfer stuff, IMO.

No experience in this, so YMMV.